# Apply LayoutTransform to DataGridTextColumn

Tags: wpf, .net-4.0, datagrid, layouttransform

I've got a `DataGrid` containing some `DataGridTextColumn`s and would like to apply a simple `LayoutTransform` to the cells, but not the header.

Problem is, `DataGridTextColumn` does not offer `LayoutTransform`.

I was able to apply `LayoutTransform`ation to a `DataGridTemplateColumn`, but I lost a whole lot of functional and was unable to build it back.

My sample so far was:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Satz">
  <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <TextBlock Margin="3,0,4,1" Text="{Binding Satz}">
        <TextBlock.LayoutTransform>
          <ScaleTransform ScaleX="1.4" ScaleY="1.4"/>
        </TextBlock.LayoutTransform>
      </TextBlock>
    </DataTemplate>
  </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
  <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <TextBox BorderThickness="0" Text="{Binding Satz, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}">
        <TextBox.LayoutTransform>
          <ScaleTransform ScaleX="1.4" ScaleY="1.4"/>
        </TextBox.LayoutTransform>
      </TextBox>
    </DataTemplate>
  </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

I'm looking for one of two ways:
- either to scale `DataGridTextColumn`.
Or, if thats not possible to
- change the `DataGridTemplateColumn` so it supports all the functionalty of the `DataGridTextColumn` (Sorting, editing) and, most important, offers the same user interface (right now the editing in the templatecolumn works different from the textcolumn).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about putting the LayoutTransform in a CellStyle?

```
    <DataGrid x:Name="dg">
        <DataGrid.Resources>
            <Style x:Key="myCellStyle" TargetType="DataGridCell">
                <Setter Property="LayoutTransform">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ScaleTransform ScaleX="1.4" ScaleY="1.4"/>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
        </DataGrid.Resources>
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn CellStyle="{StaticResource myCellStyle}" Binding="{Binding Field}"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

Comment: But somehow it does not work for me, I get an exception "" is not a valid value for property "CellStyle" (my translation from german). Looks like the staticresource somehow is empty?

Comment: Hmm... not sure why you're getting that error.  Did you copy the XAML above as is or did you make any changes to it?

Comment: Oh dang, sorry, my mistake - I had an extra line of some other stuff I tried and it contained the offending empty CellStyle - after your question I scrubbed my code and it worked!